# From parent component give style to child customized component in styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

TodoListContainer is a styled component, So Inside this container, I would like to give style to the Footer component which I import from other places.
My goal is to access different Footer inside TodoListContainer and give different CSS styles.
It is straightforward to access the regular dom element, I have a hard time accessing customized component.

Thanks for the help!

```
const TodoListContainer = styled.div`
`
```

```
  <TodoListContainer>
            <input
                className=" task-input"
                aria-label="Create a new todo..."
                type="text"
                value={text}
                placeholder="Create a new todo..."
                onChange={handleChange}
                onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            />
            <ul>
                {renderedListItems}
                <li className="footer-section">
                    <span className="itemInfor">
                        {todosRemaining} item{suffix} left
                    </span>

                    <Footer />
                    <button
                        aria-label="Clear Completed"
                        className="clear-all-btn"
                        onClick={handleClearComplete}>
                        Clear Completed
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <Footer />
        </TodoListContainer>
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think my case is a little bit different. In their example, they declare two styled-components in one file, In my case, I import the Footer component.

Comment: Imported or created in the same file does not make a difference.

Comment: So from the tutorial, If I want to reference Footer component  in my case:
This is what is tried: I add this part in the TodoListContainer 
    ${Footer} {
        display: none;
    }
However, it does not work .

Comment: The pattern looks a bit off from the example: `${Footer} & { display: none; }`

Comment: You might also try with the child selector, `> ${Footer} { display: none; }`

Comment: I tried both ways, but it seems just not working.

Comment: Keep in mind though, this will only work if `Footer` is a styled component itself.